# Printing only one group with nomencl

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I need to print only one group of my nomeclature list per page in my document. My code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature  

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomeclature Title}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item List 1}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item List 2}{}}}

\begin{document}

    \nomenclature[S]{$T_S$}{Temperature}
    \nomenclature[S]{$X_i$}{Inicial point}

    \nomenclature[A]{VHDL}{VHSIC Hardware Description Language}
    \nomenclature[A]{VHSIC}{Very High Speed Integrated Circuits}

    \printnomenclature  

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

How can I print only the list 1? or list 2?

Comment: If you want simply a page break, you can add \newpage before the item. Suppressing a nomgroup would be more difficult.

Comment: Thankyou  Ulrike Fischer. A page break helps, but I also need List 1 and List 2 as chapter style titles.